# When awarding bounty should it go to the most complete answer, or to the answer that was first?

Tags: discussion, bounty, accepted-answer

I recently posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624071/autocomplete-in-bash-script). The answer with the checkmark is complete and correct (and answered first) however the answer I awarded the bounty to was more detailed.

I feel like I should be consistent with the checkmark and the bounty, but I hate to not reward a good answer by @Euro. Note that the checkmark was awarded a day or so before the bounty. What should I do here?

Comment: The answer you received is good, but I thought I'd add that it seems odd to me to not vote up an answer you feel worthy of a bounty. (The answer currently has no votes.) Up votes are free and are the most obvious way of showing appreciation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need to be consistent - this is a very reasonable way to reward both answerers. In the end, it is *entirely* up to you which answer you accept / reward your bounty to*. If other community members disagree with you, they can upvote the answer they find the best (or even award a bounty themselves).

<sup>* except for 'reputation fraud', using bounties/votes to transfer reputation from one account to another.</sup>

Comment: Wow, that `<sup>` offset, though...

Answer (score 11):

Don't value "answered first" too much.  If someone writes a *better* answer, giving the better one the checkmark is perfectly valid.  Upvote both.

The goal of the checkmark is not just to reward the answerer, but to help the next person who comes by with your problem.  A detailed, "better" answer at the top does exactly this.

Now, the shorter answer could easily be "better", so this doesn't mean "more details = checkmark".

The bounty, in comparison, is just a "thank you" or a "this needs more attention".  I've even seen people double-bounty questions and give some to *both* good answers, while picking the better one for a checkmark.

Comment: Do you think "answered first" has _any_ value? It seems to commonly be used by OPs as a tiebreaker for very similar answers, but even that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @Don'tPanic If someone makes a post that doesn't add anything, not even a significantly different rephrasing, not really.  As a tie breaker.  As a "Well, this person answered my problem, so I'll check and never come back again".  But if you are bothering to compare?  /shrug.